# How is $E[1_X(x)] = P(X)$ where $\Omega$ is the sample space and $X \subseteq \Omega$?

Tags: probability, expected-value

How is $E[1_X(x)] = P(X)$ where $\Omega$ is the sample space and $X \subseteq \Omega$?

Suppose we toss a die. $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $X = \{1,3,5\}$, the event described by the die landing on odd numbered sides.

I read that $E [1_X] = P(X)$.

But $E[1_{X}(x)] = \sum_{x \in X} E[1_X(x)] = 3$ while $P(X) = \sum_{x \in X} P(X=x) = \frac{3}{6}$.

How are they equal?

Comment: I think there is a problem with your question. You have defined the set $X$. But you have not defined what the set $A$ is.

Comment: @EliasCosta Thanks, I meant $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I believe you mean $A$ instead of $X$ based on how you write the characteristic function (or vice versa).

Your computation of the expected value of the characteristic function is incorrect. Recall that $1_A(x)$ is 1 if x=1, 3, or 5 and 0 otherwise. If you were to take the expected value of this function, you can consider this the same as taking the average of the data set $\{1,0,1,0,1,0\}$ which would indeed be $\frac{1}{2}$ as you correctly expect.

In general, the expected value is computed as
$$E[X]=\sum x P(x)$$

In your computation you correctly identify that you should add across x values but then you compute  $P(1)=1$ which is not true. This should be $\frac{1}{6}$. Once you fix this, I believe you can see where to go from there!

Comment: I meant $X$ (or basically just any one variable).

Comment: Yes, the argument is exactly the same.

Comment: I computed it as $E[1_X (1)] = E[1] = 1$. I mean, it's always either $E[1]$ or $E[0]$, which can only add up to non-negative integers. I don't see how you get $P(1)$ from $E[1_A(1)]$.

Comment: P(1) was simply an example. You have to compute the probabilities for the same values as per the definition of the expected value function. The expected the two functions you write are not the same. By writing what you wrote here, you imply that the expected value of a function is equal to the sum of the expected value of the function value at each point. This would be akin to saying that the average value of a function is equal to simply the integral. This is why we require multiplication of the probabilities.

Comment: Well then, it doesn't answer my question, or at least, I don't understand. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The expectation of a discrete random variable $1_{X}$ is by definition
$$
E(1_X)=\sum_{x\in 1_{X}(\Omega)}x\cdot P(1_{X}=x).
$$
But $1_{X}(\Omega)=\{0,1\}$. Then
$$
E(1_X)=\sum_{x\in 1_{X}(\Omega)}x\cdot P(1_{X}=x)=0\cdot P(1_X=0)+1\cdot P(1_{X}=1)
$$ and
$$
E(1_{X})=P(1_{X}=1)
$$
by definition $P(1_{X}=1)=P([1_{X}=1])$ and the set is by definition
$$
[1_{X}=1]=\{x\in \Omega : 1_{x}(x)=1\}=X
$$
Therefore
$$
E(1_{X})=P(X).
$$

Comment: How do I prove it this way: $E[1_X] = \sum_{x \in X} E[1_X (x)] = \cdots = P(X)$? Can we say that $E[1_X (x)] = P(X = x)$ for a particular/fixed $x \in X$? It looks like it, but since $1_X(x) = 1$ is a constant, I don't see how that can be written.

Comment: I mean to say, do we treat $1_X(x)$ as the set $\{x \in \Omega : 1_X (x) = 1 \}$ or we treat it just as $1$? Ideally, it appears that we treat it as a set but there's also that possibility right? I think I am somewhere wrong with the notations as they get contradictory in my case.

Comment: The characteristic function is a function, not a set